# Android: Compile APK without debug symbols

Tags: android

I stumbled upon an [Android APK decompiler](http://www.decompileandroid.com/complete/99218?key=1253c334411105847d915cfb9bdc94d6), which can recreate the original source code very accurately.

I believe there must be some kind of debug symbols introduced when compiling (ala gcc's `-g` flag), which enables that tool to decompile the source code.

Can I disable those symbols? If not, how can I obfuscate the source code so that it cannot be decompiled this way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [ProGuard](http://developer.android.com/tools/help/proguard.html). It won't disallow decompilation but it will make it harder.

> The ProGuard tool shrinks, optimizes, and obfuscates your code by removing unused code and renaming classes, fields, and methods with semantically obscure names. The result is a smaller sized .apk file that is more difficult to reverse engineer. Because ProGuard makes your application harder to reverse engineer, it is important that you use it when your application utilizes features that are sensitive to security like when you are Licensing Your Applications.
>
> ProGuard is integrated into the Android build system, so you do not have to invoke it manually. ProGuard runs only when you build your application in release mode, so you do not have to deal with obfuscated code when you build your application in debug mode. Having ProGuard run is completely optional, but highly recommended.